# On solvable group and normalizer

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups

"
Let $G$ be finite group, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $P$ is a Sylow-p Subgroup of $G$. If $N_G(P) \leq H$, show that $N_G(H)=H.$
"

This problem appears in Martin Isaacs book under the chapter about solvable group, and I have no idea how to solve it using the concept of solvability.
Anyone can give a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have the book right here, but this seems like it wants you to use the Frattini argument. Has that been covered at this point?

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion $H \subseteq N_G(H)$ is trivial.

Now, you have that:

1. $P$ is a Sylow p-subgroup of $H$ (since $P \subseteq N_G(P) \subseteq H$)
2. $H$ is normal in $N_G(H)$ by definition of the normalizer

Hence by Frattini's argument $$N_G(H)=N_G(P)H \subseteq H$$

Comment: I am looking now at Isaac's book, and I see that this exercize is presented before introducing solvable groups, and just after introducing Sylow's theory and Frattini's argument. So, I deduce that solvability has nothing to deal with it.